# How display Chartjs full page landscape in an Ionic2 application

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, charts, ionic2

I am trying to use some charts in my Ionic 2 application. I initially played with [C3](http://c3js.org/) but have found [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059768/c3-pie-chart-not-always-updating-pie-piece-colors) using the it.

At any rate I also wanted to look at [Chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/), however I can't get this displaying to it takes up just the page when the device is rotated into landscape. While this does make the chart small on a phone, there is plenty of room on a tablet.

In portrait mode, the chart sizes itself perfectly, but not in landscape as shown below. It always seem to pick up the width of what the screen would be in portrait mode, regardless of it's current rotation.

[image]

The markup is as follows...

```
 <ion-content style='height: 100%; overflow: hidden' scroll='false' padding (window:resize)="onResize($event)">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item>
               <ion-label >Select label</ion-label>
               <ion-select >
                  <ion-option> Options 1</ion-option>
               </ion-select>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
            <canvas #pieChartCanvas>
          </canvas>   
    </ion-content>
```

In code, from an example, I have...

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.pieChart = new Chart(this.pieChartCanvas.nativeElement, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                hoverBackgroundColor: [
                    "#FF6384",
                    "#36A2EB",
                    "#FFCE56",
                    "#FF6384",
                    "#36A2EB",
                    "#FFCE56"
                ]
            }]
            ...
```

I have tried resizing the Canvas in the resize event, but this shrinks the labels as well. I just want the chart so the width and height is the min of the display height/ width (with now scrolling)

I've seen quite a few people mention they use this chart with Ionic, so if anyone does know a way around this, it would be great.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you used options for chart?

Comment: @AishApp2 I had all defaults, the only two that look like they'd make a difference are the `maintainAspectRatio` and `responsive`. I did add them just to make sure they were defaulting to `true`, which they appear to be. Is there some other option? Any other options you suggest (perhaps I've missed something)? Maybe I need to do something to it's container?

Comment: i have set only responsive to true and it works fine.